# How do I access alternate Data Stream of an NTFS file using Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, ntfs, alternate-data-stream

I am trying to solve a task in Google CTF 2019 beginner's quest. There is an NTFS file in the task. I know the file has an Alternate Data Stream (the hint mentions extended attributes).

I don't know how to access ADs in the Linux terminal. I used several tools and keywords but I could not reveal the ADs let alone access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows terms, `dir /r` doesn't show Extended Attributes; it shows [Alternate Data Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518734/dir-r-and-output-stream-in-windows-machine). (While EAs exist in Windows, they're mostly treated as a relic from OS/2.)

**Do not** extract the filesystem's contents using random tools like 7zip. This will lose most metadata (including EAs and ADSs), as these tools don't understand it and/or don't care about it. You need to inspect the file while it is still inside the original NTFS filesystem image.

- You can use ntfs-progs to inspect the image's contents:

  ```
  ntfsls -l <image>
  ntfsinfo -F <path> <image>
  ```
- You can mount the image using NTFS-3G with `streams_interface=xattr`, then just query the list of xattrs (in this mode, each NTFS stream is shown as a Linux xattr):

  ```
  attr -l <path>
  getfattr <path>
  ```
- You can mount the image using NTFS-3G with `streams_interface=windows`, then query the virtual "ntfs.streams.list" xattr:

  ```
  attr -g ntfs.streams.list <path>
  getfattr -n user.ntfs.streams.list <path>
  ```